# 2 python files and 1 main.py passing variables betwoon those files

Tags: python, variables

To make a clear structure for my project I try to keep different parts in different file.py. And I use one main.py to start the scripts together(threaded). Now I want to get one datetime.datetime variable into the other script.

For example :

```
#main.py
import file1
import file2
if __name__=='__main__':
    p1 = Process(target = file1.a)
    p1.start()
    time.sleep(1)
    p2 = Process(target = file2.b)
    p2.start()

#file1.py
def a():
    global t1
    t1 = datetime.datetime(example date)

#file2.py
def b():
    print(t1)
```

The error I get is the following :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "location\main.py", line 7, in <module>
import test2
File "location\file2", line 3, in <module>
b()
File "location\file2", line 2, in b
print(t1)
NameError: name 't1' is not defined
```

What am I doing wrong? Importing file1 in file 2 doesn't seem to work too. Should I just be putting all the scripts in one file?

If I miss any info, just ask:) Thanks!

Comment: Look into https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes

Answer (score 2):

As the traceback says, error comes from the fact that `global t1` is undefined.

If you posted the entire code, then the error is in

```
#file1.py
def a():
    global t1 # Python interpreter can not find this variable.
    t1 = datetime.datetime(example date)
```

However if you want to share ressources between processes, then consider the [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) module.

Comment: I will look onto this, thanks for your answer! I get back to this when I got answers!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
t1=0
def a():
    t1=datetime.datetime(example date)
```

setting `t1` outside of the method definition *should* make it accessible when the file is imported (`file1.t1`, obviously).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this worked almost perfect! But when running the main.py, it's printing 2 times t1 (file2.py is doing this.) So my file2.py is probably running 2 times.

Comment: When I let def a() also print t1(+other text to identify it),  I get 4 times t1 from file1 en 4 time t1 from file2. Know what i'm doing wrong? I think it goes wrong in the multithreading in main.py.